# How to install Ubuntu on original APFS Mac SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, unix, external-disk, apfs

I have a 2015 MacBook Pro 12,1 and I replaced the original 128GB SSD with an OWC Aura X2 1TB SSD. I was able to put the original 128GB SSD in an enclosure that they provide. I would like to use this original SSD as a bootable Ubuntu linux hard drive. I'm following this guide here: https://florisvanbreugel.wordpress.com/2018/03/23/installing-ubuntu-on-an-external-ssd-drive-on-a-macbook/
It says I need to erase the SSD and format it as MacOS Extended, but does not give me the option since it is an original startup SSD in APFS format. Will the process work for this drive? Anything I should change to make it work?

Comment: Which version of macOS were you running?

Comment: It was the latest one Mojave

Comment: The latest macOS is Catalina.

Comment: Yes you're right, sorry my mistake. I have Catalina running, any thoughts/ideas on my problem?

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu? Have you [created the Ubuntu installer](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-macos#0) and booted to the live version yet? This step is not in the instructions you have linked to. You might as well boot to the live version to see if you are going to have any hardware conflicts.

Comment: Can you clarify your intended use for the 128GB disk? I understand that you're using the 1TB drive for your primary macOS installation, but do you want to use the 128GB disk also within macOS, or would it just be an independent disk used for/within Ubuntu and nothing else?